# How to get gradient material to work with rig?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders, color

I've got a lil character i'm making that uses some gradient materials, but I don't know how to make the gradient move with the deformations.
[image]

[image]

as you can see, the gradient doesn't move with the deformations which makes sense with how it's setup, but I want to find a way to change that. I was hoping to avoid having to UV map because It's pretty hard for me to get such clean gradients with a texture.

here's my node setup:
[image]

Comment: UV is the best way. Try to use gradient tool in the texture paint mode (Fill brush with 'Use gradient' checked). It works nice on the texture, and on the model as well.